# expandSettingsPanel() work not well on Android5.1.1

Tags: android, android-source

On Anroid 5.1.1,
when the notification panel is not pulled down after system startup,
calling expandSettingsPanel() does not work the first 2 times.

1. in aosp project:

/frameworks/base/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/statusbar/phone/PhoneStatusBar.java

```java
public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.d(TAG, "mStatusViewClickListener");
            if (!mNotificationPanel.isFullyCollapsed()) {
                animateCollapsePanels();
            } else {
                // animateExpandNotificationsPanel();
                animateExpandSettingsPanel(); 
            }
        }
```

2. in app.

```java
public void expandSettingsPanel() {
        Log.d(TAG, "start expandSettingsPanel");
        @SuppressLint("WrongConstant") Object service = this.getSystemService("statusbar");
        if (null == service)
            return;
        try {
            Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("android.app.StatusBarManager");
            Method expand = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("expandSettingsPanel");
            expand.setAccessible(true);
            expand.invoke(service);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```